# Стоит ли использовать isset

Tags: php

Мои настройки php и настройки php на хостинге не ругаются если использовать запись`if ($_POST['specialist_id']) {...}`.

Хорошему программисту на php лучше использовать `if (isset($_POST['specialist_id'])) {...}`или не возбраняется писать просто `if ($_POST['specialist_id']) {...}`?

Comment: Если точно уверены, что такая переменная есть, то можно и без isset(), в противном случае лучше перестраховаться и использовать, что бы ошибки не сыпались.

Comment: рекомендую всегда использовать `isset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендую всегда использовать `isset()` в данном контексте.

Comment: так, и что будет если не использовать `isset` в данном случае?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский по правильному будет варнинг "такого ключа нет". Но это ж пхп, а значит все зависит от версии пхп и настройки.

Comment: @vitidev доказательства можно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тут http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ вбейте код $arr=array('foo'=>'bar');print($arr['foo2']); и выполните.

Comment: @vitidev нет нет нет. мы сейчас про POST запрос говорим

Comment: @АлексейШиманский $_POST точно такой же массив, как и другие.

Comment: @vitidev окей, гляну проверю

Answer (score 4):

isset проверяет на существование переменную или элемент массива. А сам if проверяет уже значение. Это совершенно разные конструкции. 
Рекомендуеться проверять и на наличие переменной и само значение.

Answer (score 2):

```
+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+
|$var               | isset($var) | if($var)          |
+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+
|не задана          | false       | false + E_NOTICE  |
+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+
|приводится к false | true        | false             |
|[],"",false,0,"0"  |             |                   |
+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+
|приводится к true  | true        | true              |
+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Для полного эквивалента вашего условия нужно проверять не только что переменная задана, но и что значение у нее есть:

```
if (!empty($_POST['specialist_id'])) {
    // эквивалент isset($_POST['specialist_id']) && $_POST['specialist_id']
}
```

Другим вариантом может быть отключить ругань в вашем варианте:

```
if (@$_POST['specialist_id'])) {

}
```

Впрочем на последний многие будут смотреть с опаской и подозрением.

Comment: забавно, но **[доки говорят](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php)** что `empty() фактически является точным эквивалентом конструкции !isset($var) || $var == false` ............ Вопрос: зачем проверять, что переменная задана и еще вдобавок `empty`, который делает тоже самое?

Comment: Вы отрицание перед `empty()` не заметили наверное.

Answer (score -2):

Если в `$_POST` не будет `['key']`, то есть `$_POST['key']` не будет установлен, будет выведен `NOTICE`, а если сделать `isset($_POST['key'])` то даже, если этот ключ не будет определен, `NOTICE` не будет.
В отличии от `empty` конструкция `isset` поддерживает оператор `and so on`, по этому мы можем использовать такой синтаксис: `isset($_POST['key'], $_POST['key2'])`, чего нельзя делать с `empty`.

Проверку на то, что переменная или ключ массива существует, нужно делать только в том случае, если вы не уверены, что этой переменной или ключа массива может не быть.
Это относится к тем областям. где переменная или ключ массима создается динамически или может быть удален в ходе.